# Receiving SMS message in Android- Script has unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I use this code to receive SMS messages. When the phone receives an SMS message, I get a message that this script has stopped. Can anyone please help?

ReceivesmsActivity.java

```
     public class ReceivesmsActivity extends Activity {
public TextView info;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_receivesms);
            info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
            info.setText("Good");
            }
public class Receivesms extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
     try{ 
     Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
     Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
     SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]); 
     info.setText(messages.getMessageBody());
     }catch(Exception e){
     Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }
 }
```

And this is my manifest file for receiving SMS messages:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
        <receiver android:name=".ReceivesmsActivity">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
         </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: When the your application receives SMS is it in background or foreground ?

Comment: is your broadcast receiver class declared inside of activity? please put braces correctly

Comment: foreground @Kedarnath

Comment: by the way, you've included your Activity as Receiver in your manifest

Comment: it must be inside activity or application? @mangusta

Comment: @user3278612 see the answer below. and correct your manifest - it should include `ReceivesmsActivity` registered in `<activity>` tag and `Receivesms` registered in `<receiver>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you an alaternate way by following code,

```
public class ReceivesmsActivity extends Activity 
{
        private static TextView info;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_receivesms);
            info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
            info.setText("Good");
        }


        public void setInfoText ( String str )
        {
             info.setText ( str ); 
        }
}

public class Receivesms extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {  
         try
        {
            Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage messages =SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]); 
            //info.setText(messages.getMessageBody());
             ReceivesmsActivity.setInfoText ( messages.getMessageBody().toString() );
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    }
}
```